# scanner issue when copy pasted but the original program works

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, type-mismatch

```
       int x = 0;
       int y = 0;       
        /**modify grade*/
        Scanner student = new Scanner(System.in);             
        System.out.print("Enter student ID:");
        int studentId = student.nextInt();

        switch (studentId){
        case 1101:
            Scanner course = new Scanner(System.in);              
            System.out.print("Enter course ID:");
            int courseID = course.nextInt();

            switch(courseID){
            case 901:
                x = 1;
                y = 1;

                Scanner change = new Scanner(System.in);              
                System.out.print("Enter new value:");
                int newGrade = change.nextInt();

                aryTable[x][y] = newGrade;//problem here

                break;

            break;
        }
```

with the "newGrade;" it has a red underlined saying type mismatch, but everything seems to be fine, even the 2 scanners used previously work. it was just a copy paste, im confused as to why this is wrong? can i pls get any help to make this valid? i am making a program that will get the student, then get the course, then modify the corresponding grade.. i used a 2-d array.. thanks and cheers

Comment: Can you please add the declaration of aryTable, because that seems to be the problem

Comment: what is type of aryTable

Comment: nvm, found the problem, i was using a different table, thank you for pointing that out(or should i say asking for that) cheers

Comment: not quite sure how to give thumbs up or something, but yeah, anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you are doing is incorrect, that is not the way to initialize or use multidimensional array.  Try the following code,

```
x=1;
y=1;    
int aryTable[][]=new int[x][y];    
aryTable[0][x-1]=newGrade;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define arraytable like this.

```
int[][] arrayTable;
```

The problem is that you are assigning an int value to a 2d array of another type.